# Android software that can read e-books with embedded real-person voices corresponding to the text

Tags: android, ebooks

I am looking for a software for Android 4.4.2 which can read the text of an e-book aloud (either using Text-to-Speech (TTS) or by playing custom-recorded-voices embedded in the e-book), not just display the text. Please include an example app and step by step instructions on how to do this in your answer. I tried with kindle but could not find the procedure on how to do this. Thanks.

UPDATE: I have found the wonderful "Moon+ Pro Reader" at around 5$ which does pdf and e-book reading via TTS and also allows to insert tags and notes, as well as the costly OCR to text with TTS "KNFB Reader" at 99 $.

What *I have not found* is a software I can use to

1. embed and intertwine my own studio's real people's voices to a document's prewritten text. The software should include voice recognition so as to automatically place a marker in the file before and after each word.
2. A file format (if one does not already exist), to store the voice fragments together with the text in a file.
3. A client file allowing the user to read, fast forward or fast backwards N paragraphs, sentences, words, play, pause, spell current word, repeat a number of words between a start and end marker any number of times, perhaps even insert a text or voice annotation.

What fileformats support this functionality and where can I get (preferably Android-compatible) software to record and listen to such a file? Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean read the book aloud? Is it text to speech that you are after? Any particular eBook format? Must the app be free, or do you have a budget?

Comment: I have not looked extensively, but maybe [in here](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/search?q=text+to+speech+android)

Comment: I have updated my post. Please have a look.